# Noise from Hood (front grill) Engine Off

Tags: honda, noise, accord, fan

I have a 2008 Honda Accord EX 3.5L V6, with about 152k mileage.

Very recently, after driving for about 15-20 minutes of a normal commute, I shut my car off, there is a noise (fan-like) noise coming from the hood (front grill) which lasts for maybe 5-8 minutes then stops. I am very concerned with this, as this had never happened, the temp gauge on my dashboard is at middle (normal) but when I do open the hood, it does feel like it’s excessive hot (though this is subjective).

Following some research, I understand that this noise may be the radiator fan, though unsure of it, it is trying to cool down my engine, is this normal? It’s just concerning as this never happened before and my driving distances are essentially the same as before.

Edit: After a few days I have come to a founding: This tends to occur if I have my car on idle for a while like 10-15 minutes on idle, then brief driving and idle again for 5-10 minutes (Just looking for parking space at campus)

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It is not uncommon for the fans to stay on after the vehicle is shut off. This is how it is designed to work if the engine coolant is too hot.

If it is new behavior that the fans are staying on yet nothing has changed and the dash gauge isn't showing a temperature issue, it may be that the engine coolant temperature sensor might be going bad. The type of behavior you are describing is typical of the failure of this sensor.

There is also a fan timer module which may be failing. This is what keeps the fans running after the vehicle is shut down. If the ECT sensor is good, this is most likely the culprit.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind after I take it to the mechanic and kind of cross reference it with that they say